# Assign image to an ImpressPages page

Tags: php, impresspages

I want to have a custom header image on per page basis. How to create management to assign an image to each page? I've tried to use GRID (http://www.impresspages.org/docs/grid) to add a list of images. But how to assign them to the page ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the free PageImage plugin https://github.com/impresspages-plugins/PageImage